# RHEL 5 list missing critical patches/packages

Tags: linux, redhat, unix, rpm, patch-management

Im trying to figure out if there is an easy way to identify the missing critical patches/packages on my RHEL5 boxes. This is for audit purposes and was trying to figure out if there was an RPM command or something of the sort that would accomplish this easily.

I know with my Solaris 10 boxes, i can run the "smpatch analyze" command which would display this information for me. Anyone know of anything similar for RHEL5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Install the yum-security plugin and use `yum --security check-update`:

```
[root@camel ~]# yum --security check-update
Loaded plugins: puppet, security
Limiting package lists to security relevant ones
Needed 1 of 219 packages, for security

proftpd.x86_64                        1.3.3g-3.el5                         epel
```

Answer (score 2):

The typical reporting tool for RHEL servers with valid Red Hat support contracts is the Red Hat network [Red Hat Network](https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/systems/SystemList.do) if they're registered online.

Alternatively they could be managed from a Red Hat network satellite.

Reporting missing errata is usually more relevant then packages because it includes severity ratings which makes auditors happy.

It doesn't help with reporting on software installed from source, additional non-Red Hat yum repositories and such[image]